# Second dropdown list based on First dropdown with only php and html

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a dropdown list `Year` made in php with years from current year until current year+10:

```
<p>Year:
        <select name="sel_year">
<?php
    $year=date("Y")-1;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) 
    {   
        $year = $year+1;
        echo("<option value=\"$year\">$year</option>");
    } 
?>      
    </select>
```

And I want to make a second dropdown list with `months` that are based on the selection made on the previous list (`Year`), the thing is that I can only use html and php and I need to do this on the same page and, if possible, without using a submit button.
This is what I have so far:

```
<p>Month:
    <select name="sel_month">
<?php
    if(sel_year==(date("Y")))
    {
        for ($month = date("m"); $month <= 12; $month++) 
        {       
            $monthName = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10));
            echo("<option value=\"$month\">$monthName</option>");
        }   
    }
?>      
    </select>
```

In this part I only want to allow the user to select the months from now until December (inclusive) if the selected year previously is the same year as we're in. Any ideas?

Comment: What if the user selects next year, are they allowed to select the previous months? Or would they only be able to select november / december anyway?

Comment: They would be able to choose the next months yes, bit i havent added that part of the code because i cant get the if to work

Comment: you need to use get parametr for year

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You will not be able to do this on the same page without javascript. If the month selection is on a different page, you would be able to use a parameter or variable to check if the year is the current year and base your month selection on that. PHP runs on the server and sends out a HTML page. That means your code will only run when the user navigates to another page.

Comment: Can i use the submit button or refresh the page to go around that?

Comment: You can submit the page and show the month dropdown on another page, this way you will have a $_GET or $_POST parameter containing the submitted year. You can then decide whether to show all months or only those left in this year.

Comment: I think i will just let the user select any Month XD